# Verifying a dowload after clicking on download button using selenium for automation testing

Tags: java, selenium, automation

Is there a way to check(for automation testing) whether a dowload has started or not, when clicked on a download button (clicked using selenium)?

Assume that save dialog box has been supressed in whichever browser I use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, AFAIK with Selenium you cant check if download is in progress. But you can check the file once it is downloaded.
[**Link**](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/) for more details.